# How is the total memory of consumption in a parallel MPI code computed? Is it simply the number of processors times memory used in a serial code?

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

To give you more context, I have huge arrays that are partially used by all processes. Currently, I don't have local arrays defined storing only the portion needed for the concerned process since it is a time-consuming process and parallelizing the code itself took a long time. So, my fear is that this might be resulting in a huge memory requirement though I am tempted not to jump to any conclusion due to my lack of knowledge of the working principles of MPI. Currently, the code throws up segmentation faults with "out of memory" messages.

An update- I was able to define local arrays of dimensions commensurate with the required information for the concerned processor. However, I ran into another problem, for which I have to create a separate post. So, I guess it's safe to close this post.

Comment: If you allocate the full array on each process, the total memory required is the number of processes multiplied by the memory required for that array. Allocating just what you need should not, IMO, be an afterthought but the first thing you think of. If you do it that way around the parallel speed up tends to come naturally.

Comment: I must second what Ian wrote. You should start from the data distribution. That is the key to distributed parallelism (=parallelism with processes that do not share memory).

Comment: If your huge arrays are partially used by the processes, do they access disjoint parts? If yes, allocate only that part, and shift the indices. Done. If no, then I wonder if your code is correct: do you think that the huge arrays are somehow shared memory? They are not. If process A writes something in a location that process B will read, this does not work: you need a send operation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.